# jquery .show() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this h1 element:

```
<h1><a id="toobin">Text here</a></h1>
```

Im using this to try and show it:

```
$("#nav_list").click(function() {
    $("h1:gt(0)").hide();
    $("#toobin h1").show();
});
```

The first line hides all of my h1 elements and trying to show just the one too bin h1 element won't work.
If I do this `$("h1").show();` I can get all of the h1 elements to show. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: h1 is parent of toobin..

Comment: try $("h1 #toobin").show();

Comment: @DilipRajkumar That won't work. An element won't be shown if it's inside a hidden element.

Comment: Why not put the ID on the `<h1>` instead of the `<a>`? `<h1 id="toobin"><a>Text here</a></h1>`

Comment: $("h1 #toobin").show(); does not work, :has() did though.

Comment: You may use $("#toobin").parents('h1').show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
$("h1:has(#toobin)").show();
```

The `:has(<selector>)` modifier selects elements that contain an element matching the parenthesized selector.

`#toobin h1` means all `h1` that are inside `#toobin`, but `#toobin` is inside the `h1`.

```js
$("#nav_list").click(function() {
    $("h1:gt(0)").hide();
    $("h1:has(#toobin)").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>First, won't be hidden</h1>
<h1>Will be hidden</h1>
<h1>Will also be hidden</h1>
<h1><a id="toobin">Should stay</a></h1>
<h1>Another hidden one</h1>
<button id="nav_list">Click to hide</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `:has`.

Comment: Can't you simply do : $("#toobin").show() , whats the need of has selector ?

Comment: @DinoMyte An element won't be shown if it's inside a hidden element.